# How to solve "Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length"?

Tags: encryption, rsa, bouncycastle, public-key, pem

I am using bouncycastle library to generate the public key.
I am decoding public key like this:

```
var cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
var certificate = cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Certificate)));
```

where base64Certificate is string generated by bouncycastle (initially in pem format).

I am getting this error:

> Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you generating a publickey or a certificate? They are different things, and CertificateFactory can't read a publickey -- but that should cause a different error. Your error looks more like decoding PEM as if it were plain base64, which it is not; depending on which decoder that may 'decode' the BEGIN and END lines, producing garbage in your data and making it unparseable as DER. Can you be clear and/or give a complete example?